# Error: exec proxy not found for :: LocalNotification :: deviceready

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

I am new to Cordova and Phonegap and I am trying to develop a reminder application. I used cordova-plugin-local-notifications ( https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications ). 
I installed the plugin using the the installation command

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notification

Then I tried to run the app on the browser and there was an error on browser console:

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: LocalNotification :: deviceready

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Questions:**

1. What is this problem?
2. What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Hey Afnan, if my answer has provided you all the answers you needed, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The plugin is simply not supported on the browser platform.

[See the docs](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) as of 10th of April, 2017:

> ## Supported Platforms
>
> ---
>
> The current 0.8 branch supports the following platforms:
>
> - iOS (>= 8)
> - Android (SDK >=7)
> - Windows 8.1 (added with v0.8.2)
> - Windows Phone 8.1 (added with v0.8.2)
> - Windows 10 (added with v0.8.3)

Your browser console states that it can not execute the plugin, since it supports only the mobile OS stated above.

Answer (score -2):

needs https connection..otherwise chrome/firefox gonna block it..

localhost will work though.

can try this for free certificate 
https://letsencrypt.org/